# Unable to install MariaDB after deleting /var/lib/mysql, because mysql.user exists

Tags: linux, mysql, manjaro

I tried to install MariaDB on my system (Manjaro) and after install with `mariadb-install-db` I couldn't get the service running. I figured this was because I run the command without root (I was surprised it even run as unprivileged user) but after deleting everything in /var/lib/mysql, I couldn't run `mariadb-install-db` any more, because a table mysql.user exists. The command says to run `mariadb-upgrade` instead, but that fails because it needs a running server - and I can't get a running server without installing it first.

I tried using `--force` flag but that doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I force `mariadb-install-db` to run after manually deleting /var/lib/mysql? How can there be a table already present, if the datadir is empty?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, `mariadb` on Manjaro by default installs database to `./data` instead of `/var/lib/mysql`, regardless of user running it.

I installed `mariadb` server on Mint another day and it did the same thing of installing the database system-wide by default. On Manjaro, you have to specify `--datadir=/var/lib/mysql` to install the database in the default system location instead of current directory.